# how to insert Qframe.ui to QMainWindow with pyside6?

Tags: python, pyside6

I am making a GUI with Python, Qt, PySide6 and QTDesigner. The idea is to create a main window with a container to which different frames will be added for each process that my application will carry out.

For this I designed the main window mainWindow.ui (QMainWindow) in QtDesigner and added a QVBoxLayout as a container, and to the latter I added my frame 1. Then I designed subframe2.ui (QFrame) and subFrame3.ui (QFrame). Lastly, I converted all three .ui files to .py

- ui_mainWindow.py
- ui_subFrame2.py
- ui_subFrame3.py

then create the main file main.py:

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton,QVBoxLayout,QWidget)

from ui_mainWindow import Ui_MainWindow
from ui_subFrame2 import Ui_Frame_2
from ui_subFrame3 import Ui_Frame_3


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

    self.window = Ui_MainWindow()       
    self.window.setupUi(self)
    self.window.frame_1.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;") 
                    
    self.subFrame2 = Ui_Frame_2()       
    self.subFrame2.setupUi(self)
    self.subFrame2.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;") 

    self.subFrame3 = Ui_Frame_3()       
    self.subFrame3.setupUi(self)
    self.subFrame3.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: blue;")

    '''###############  test one ###############'''
    #self.window.verticalLayout_container.addWidget(self.subFrame2)
    #self.window.verticalLayout_container.addWidget(self.subFrame3)

    '''###############  test two ###############'''
    #widget = QWidget()
    #layout = QVBoxLayout()
    #layout.addWidget(self.subFrame2)
    #layout.addWidget(self.subFrame3)           
    #widget.setLayout(layout)
    #self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

With the above code the window that is drawn is:

[image: window draw]

and what i expected is this:

[image: window expected]

I have performed test one and two (commented code).

1. test one throws me the following error

   $ python main.py
   QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MainWindow "MainWindow", which already has a layout
   QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MainWindow "MainWindow", which already has a layout
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:QFRAME_SAMPLE\main.py", line 41, in 
   window = MainWindow()
   File "C:QFRAME_SAMPLE\main.py", line 26, in **init**
   self.window.verticalLayout_container.addWidget(self.subFrame2)
   TypeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget' called with wrong argument types:
   PySide6.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget(Ui_Frame_2)
   Supported signatures:
   PySide6.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget(PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget, int = 0, PySide6.QtCore.Qt.Alignment = Default(Qt.Alignment))
2. test twothrows me the following error

   $ python main.py
   QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MainWindow "MainWindow", which already has a layout
   QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to MainWindow "MainWindow", which already has a layout
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:QFRAME_SAMPLE\main.py", line 41, in 
   window = MainWindow()
   File "C:QFRAME_SAMPLE\main.py", line 32, in **init**
   layout.addWidget(self.subFrame2)
   TypeError: 'PySide6.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget' called with wrong argument types:
   PySide6.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget(Ui_Frame_2)
   Supported signatures:
   PySide6.QtWidgets.QBoxLayout.addWidget(PySide6.QtWidgets.QWidget, int = 0, PySide6.QtCore.Qt.Alignment = Default(Qt.Alignment))

For those two errors change the code of ui_subFrame2.py and ui_subFrame3.py:

from this

```
class Ui_Frame_2(object):
class Ui_Frame_3(object):
```

to this

```
class Ui_Frame_2(QFrame):
class Ui_Frame_3(QFrame):
```

and changing in main this

```
self.subFrame3.setStyleSheet("background-color: #222222;")
self.subFrame2.setStyleSheet("background-color: #999999;")
```

I draw the following window

[image: Window_end]

it seems that the Qframes are adjusted but all the elements inside are messed up

if you could guide me I would appreciate it

Comment: There are two problems: 1. you're always calling `setupUi(self)`, which attempts to set the *ui* to `self` (which is the `MainWindow` instance) many times; 2. you're doing that using a form class based on QWidget (which has its own layout) but QMainWindow has its own *internal* layout, which could not be overridden. Also, changing the code of the generated python files won't help (and doing it is frown upon). We can provide an answer, but it's better if you first clarify if you intend to have a main window with the first frame and those other 2 widgets as separate objects, or *all* of them.

Comment: Thank you @musicamante for your prompt response

I want to have a main window (QMainWindow.ui) to load 3 frames (QFrame.ui) or more that are in different files, when loading them in the main window I can hide or show them according to what the user chooses.

NOTE: my program has a side menu that is the one that activates or deactivates each frame once it has them inside mainWindow. I know that I could do this with a QStackedWidget, however I have many components and the QMainWindow.ui would be overloaded, so I am separating them into several ui, so that the code is organized

Comment: Then: 1. create a main window in Designer, *without* any of those frames (remove the existing frame, but leave the existing layout). 2. create *all* those frames as standard widgets (not main windows) in Designer; 3. add them to the main window by creating separate QWidget instances and call `someform.setupUi()` with *those* instances, **not** `self`.

Comment: I have already done the three steps you mention, creating a main window (QMainWindow) and three frames (QWidget), and calling `frame1.setupUi()` however it gives me an error: `TypeError: Ui_Form.setupUi() missing 1 required positional argument: ' Form'`

Comment: Because, as said, you have to call that function using the instance of QWidget, not `self`, and certainly not without any argument: `self.frame1 = QWidget()` `self.frame1_ui = Ui_Frame_1()` `self.frame1_ui.setupUi(self.frame1)`. But I'd suggest you to just go with the multiple inheritance approach described in the guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html), using subclasses, and directly add instances of them to the layout.

Comment: @musicamante thank you very much you have clarified the subject a lot, it already works for me with the three methods that are in [Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) (direct approach, single and multiple inheritance), and as you suggest I like the multiple inheritance method more (cleaner and more maintainable code) , however I have a question about this approach, can a class derived from `frame1.ui` modify an element `QLabe` of another class `frame2.ui`, When both classes are instantiated from `QMainWindow`?